# How to deal with a media-type for error messages of the Cowboy REST handler

Tags: rest, erlang, cowboy, media-type

I want the user to have the opportunity to choose the format in which it receives a response from the server, whether it is plain text, json or xml. It's looks like I must to retrieve media_type by calling cowboy_req:meta/{2,3} and then use it for encoding a response body. But that value doesn't available in callbacks before content_types_provided (malformed_request, is_authorized, forbidden...).

Should I dublicate a cowboy logic and write my own code to determine media_type?

Or ignore all callbacks which had executed before the media_type has been determined.

Or maybe should I to place my response message into request metadata and encode it in the onresponse hook, then replace response body?

How should I do that?

Comment: I often make a hard decision: "All status code response bodies will be text/plain" (or application/json). This is easier to manage.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not quite wright. Straight from `init/3` and `rest_init/3` functions the `Request` parameter is "full request", and you can read any header or meta in each callback.

And personally i would go with Header over Meta (since there is already `Content-Type` header defined, and Headers should take presence over Meta).

In general the REST callbacks in cowboy should only give you easily understandable workflow for handling request, with additional default response codes. In `is_authorized/2` all you need to do is check authorization, simply return true or false (as part of tuple), and cowboy will either move forward with you logic or return `401` code. Checking is someone allowed to make request should not be determined on response format, but still, if you would like to do it, just read this Meta from `Req` parameter, and return true/false based on it.

And the only difference with `content_types_provided/2` is that you return kind of bindings between `Content-Types` header values and your functions. I think all you need could be based on this [official example](https://github.com/extend/cowboy/blob/master/examples/rest_hello_world/src/toppage_handler.erl#L15)

Comment: In my case I want to return a response body with a human-readable message on each request. Of course I can ignore request's meta and work with headers only. In this case I need to read the value of Accept header, then compare it with content_types_provided list and then finally I will know the right format for the response body. All that logic are already defined in a cowboy code and therefore I'm looking for a way not to reimplement it.